# Making GUI that works with C++ code

Tags: c++, user-interface, debian

How would you make a GUI in debian linux system that goes along with my C++ program to display a variable from my C++ code?
I have my C++ program on loop and have the GUI display informations I want while it constantly updates.
If there are easier way than to make GUI to do this does anyone have an idea how?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple different GUI frameworks for C++.  Check out [Qt](http://qt-project.org/), or these [GTK](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk-tutorial/2.90/) examples

Comment: Right, I guess my point is to look.  This question can be answered with a simple google search